# How to view committed kafka message only

Tags: apache-kafka

I am currently using Kadeck community and sometimes commands on docker to view messages saved on kafka, but now I am testing transactional semantics and I want only to view committed messages. I am having a hard time to do this. Anyone know how to view committed messages only even using other 3rd party application such as Kadeck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the kafka tools:

```
kafka-consumer-groups  --bootstrap-server broker01.example.com:9092 --describe --group your_group
```

This command shows the state of topics of a consumer-group:

```
GROUP        TOPIC  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG     OWNER
your-group   t1     0          1               3               2       test-consumer
```

To see the committed messages you must read from the beginning until the current-offset with kafka-console-consumer or another kafka client.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is still relevant. But this is now possible in KaDeck directly via the topic inspector.

But you will only see "committed" messages in KaDeck anyway (read_committed).